# Angular calling a function once the subscription has populated

Tags: angular, angularfire2, angular2-observables

Having trouble getting the correct value to the view logic.

Basically service is called, its runs through and populates an array, I then need it to call a private function when the array code is complete.

```
calculateSemesterGPA(semesterId: string, userId: string) {

let gradesArr = [];
let resultsArr = [];
let result;

this.getSemesterGrades(semesterId).valueChanges()
.subscribe(snapshots => {
  snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
    gradesArr.push(snapshot.grade)  
  });
});

this.getScales(userId).valueChanges()
.subscribe(snapshots => {
  snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
    for(let i = 0; i < gradesArr.length; i++) {
      if(gradesArr[i] === snapshot.letter) {
        resultsArr.push(snapshot.points);
      }
    }
    result = this.CalculateGPA(resultsArr)
  });
})

return result;
```

}

```
/*
    Function to calculate the gpa score of an array passed in.
*/
private CalculateGPA(gradePoints: number[]) {

    let length = gradePoints.length;
    let total = 0;

    for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      total += (gradePoints[i]*1);
    }

    // returns the total grade score divided by the amount of grades in the array.
    console.log(total / length)
    return (total / length);
}
```

I know the private function is working correctly as it console.log's the correct values. But it seems the original function is returning the result without waiting for the this.getScales part to complete. I've tried returning directly from inside that part as well.

Comment: Either you re-declare you result as a class property and use `this.result=this.CalculateGPA(resultsArr)` or you could use `setTimeout(()=>{
     return result
 },1000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning outside your `subscription`, so while your `subscription` is going and fetching data and doing the calculations, you have already returned. Returning inside the subscription is also not a good idea. And where do you expect to see the `return`? What is `valueChanges()`. A `subscribe` will return a `Subscription`. Why don't you make `result` as a class variable and directly assign it like this inside your subscription:

```
this.result = this.CalculateGPA(resultsArr);
```

Now if you really have to return from that method of your, then don't `subscribe` but rather do a `map` and:

```
return this.getScales(userId).valueChanges().map(() => {
    ...
    return result
    ...
})
```

and then you have to `subscribe` to the returned value.

**EDIT**

I just saw that you have put the subscriptions one after the other under one method: `calculateSemesterGPA(semesterId: string, userId: string) {}`.
We can't tell which subscription will succeed first. Please nest the second subscription under the first, so that you are really sure, that thet the second runs only after first has finished.

```
this.getSemesterGrades(semesterId).valueChanges()
   .subscribe(snapshots => {
      snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
         gradesArr.push(snapshot.grade)  
      });

      this.getScales(userId).valueChanges()
        .subscribe(snapshots => {
          snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
          for(let i = 0; i < gradesArr.length; i++) {
            if(gradesArr[i] === snapshot.letter) {
              resultsArr.push(snapshot.points);
            }
          }
         this.result = this.CalculateGPA(resultsArr)
         });
        })    
   });
```

Comment: .valueChanges() is part of angularfire to return the subscription. I need the subscription to create the array with the .forEach loop. I then take this result which might be [7, 7, 6, 5] for example. The private function then calculates the average and returns this single value, but it can't do it without the subscription loop being completed.  So I need to fire off the call this.CalculateGPA() once the subscription has returned its array.

Comment: @theHussle: Okay.. is there any further calculations required with the returned `result`? or you just have to show the result in the view?

Comment: Im just wanting to show the result in the view in that example it would be 6.25. I made the calculation a seperate private function so it can be used elsewhere..

Comment: @theHussle: Okay, then please make the `result` as a `class` variable. something like, `public result: number` just after your class starts will do. Inside your subscription. you assign as I have suggested in my answer. Plus there seems to be something really wrong with the way you have added the `subscriptions`. I will update my answer for that.

Comment: I've updated the function but it does something weird and runs twice. Then when calling it with this.GPA = this.gradesProvider.calculateSemesterGPA(this.semesterKey, this.userId); 

this.GPA doesnt get assigned until I reload. Never had this kind of problem before...

Comment: @theHussle: can't say why it's getting called twice and why are you trying to assign the return value? We are not returning anything from the function, that is why I asked to assign the value to a class property. And directly access the class property in your view. Remember, if we return a subscription we get a subscription instance as the return value, not what you have returned inside the subscription.

Comment: As ashish mentioned it makes no sense to return something in an async call if you depend on it. I would recommend to use it as a Promise and save the data somewhere. And access it then. If you need the data directly after you called your function considering to change the function to a promise aswell or return the promise which contains the data